# How to reduce multiple if conditions into a single shortened condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are multiple if conditions performing replacement of strings with the string KAP:

```
var nameList = $('#name').text();

if(nameList.indexOf('SAM') > -1){
    var newName = nameList.replace(/SAM/g, 'KAP');
    $('#name').html(newName);
}

if(nameList.indexOf('PAT') > -1){
    var newName = nameList.replace(/PAT/g, 'KAP');
    $('#name').html(newName);
}
```

How can the above two be condensed into a single if condition using jquery/javascript if we have the new names already present in an array as below

var nameArray = ['SAM','PAT','DAB'];

such that if any of the above is found in nameList no other condition gets checked.

Comment: If you have an array of names, why not loop over the array & try matching each one in turn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nameList = $('#name').text();

var nameArray = ['SAM','PAT','DAB'];
nameArray.some(function(name) {
    if (!!~nameList.indexOf(name)) {
        nameList.replace(new RegExp(name, 'gi'), 'KAP');
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Array.some method iterates through array's elements until the function returns true.
Checkout [Mozilla Developers documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

!!~ is a combination of operands which makes only -1 false.

Answer (score 0):

At its most basic I'd suggest:

```
var nameArray = ['SAM','PAT','DAB'],
    reg = new RegExp('(' + nameArray.join('|') + ')', 'i'),
if (reg.test(nameList)) {
    // one of those names was found
}
else {
    // none of those names were found
}
```

[Simplified JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WxQ6h/).

Answer (score 0):

Here, you go:

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2F4dG/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="name">Hi my name is Sam. Sam is cool.</div>
```

**CODE**

```
$(function(){
    var nameList = $('#name').text()

    var nameArray = ['SAM','PAT','DAB'];

    //loop through all possible names
    for(var i=0;i<nameArray.length;i++){
        if(nameList.toUpperCase().indexOf(nameArray[i])!=-1){
            //new regex out of name we are replacing...
            var re = new RegExp(nameArray[i],"gi");
            //replacae all matches
            var newName = nameList.replace(re,"KAP");
            //set new name
            $('#name').html(newName);
            //exit loop we found our match...
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

**OUTPUT**

`Hi my name is KAP. KAP is cool.`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any if/else statements - you can just use a regex

```
var nameArray = ['SAM','PAT','DAB'];// your list of words
var nameList = $('#name').text();// your string to check
var reg = new RegExp(nameArray.join('|'),"g");// create the regex object - reg == /SAM|PAT|DAB/g
$('#name').html(nameList.replace(reg,'KAP'));
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/UjLUw/)